# Ionic emulate ios results in black screen after accepting new XCode agreement

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I recently updated XCode. I also updated OSX to El Capitan.

Now I can't emulate my ionic app in ios anymore.

**Problem 1:** Now I have to type `sudo ionic emulate ios` (before I didn't need sudo)

**Problem 2:** When I emulate, the simulator launches and I get a completely black screen. The console outputs this error:

```
2015-10-08 13:14:38.486 ios-sim[7223:306928] stderrPath: /Users/Foad/Documents/My apps/quedro-ionic/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2015-10-08 13:14:38.486 ios-sim[7223:306928] stdoutPath: /Users/Foad/Documents/My apps/quedro-ionic/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2015-10-08 13:14:38.551 ios-sim[7223:306928] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-8208/DVTFoundation/PlugInArchitecture/PlugInManager/DVTPlugInManager.m:257
Details:  Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DVTFoundation.DevicePlatformMapping
Object:   <DVTPlugInManager: 0x7fbad174fd10>
Method:   -extensionPointWithIdentifier:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fbad140dd80>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

I have no idea what any of this means. Everyone on my team is having the same problem. Is the ionic team aware of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exact same problem and followed the steps on [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/warning-when-emulating-ios/33822/3)

```
1. Uninstall cordova 
2. Delete .cordova (hidden) directory from ~/
3. Delete platforms/ and plugins/ directories from my ionic project
4. npm install ios-sim -g
5. npm install ios-deploy -g
6. Make sure all the dependencies I have in package.json up to date
7. npm install
8. npm install cordova -g
9. ionic state reset
10. ionic emulate ios
```

I had also the **sudo** issue, so I changed the permissions on node_modules in the project and ~/.npm.